# Search function on recyclerView in fragment

Tags: android

I want to a search function on `RecyclerView` in fragment , i had set the search view icon successfully .   I remain the function for search now.

I take some tutorial ,some use github and some use the variable i can't know it , i still can't understand them.

I just know it looks like i need filter the data , but i have no idea how to do . Just write a filter function on `MyAdapter` extends `RecyclerView` ? and how ?

Is anyone can tell me ? any help will be grateful.

It's my fragment create menu:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.search));
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));


        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

I implements the interface to override two function:

```
public class ActivityListDomesticFragment extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
       //I just know i have set the filter right here
        return false;
    }
}
```

It's my `RecyclerView` class about constructor:

```
public class MyAdapterForList extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapterForList.MyViewHolder>{

    private Context context;
    private List<ActivityListItem> mDatas;

    public MyAdapterForList(Context context, List<ActivityListItem> datas) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        mDatas = datas;
    }
```

Comment: create two arraylist of your recycler data. and match your search text with second list and matched list put into first one. and notify

Comment: So i declare List<ActivityListItem> secondDatas;  and new MyAdapterForList(getActivity,secondDatas);   is that so ?

Comment: use [this](https://gist.github.com/pskink/cd3bbdd742b5b1905a790c76831b5d85) generic adapter and override its `matches()` method

Comment: do you mean gradle it , and override mathes on  onQueryTextChange ?

Comment: i mean: create `class Adapter extends MatchableRVArrayAdapter<ActivityListItem, Adapter.VH> { ...` and override `matches()` method in that class, inside `onQueryTextChange ` just call `adapter.getFilter().filter(newText)`, thats all

Comment: so i need to change extends Fragment to extends MatchableRVArrayAdapter...  is that so ?

Comment: no, you have to change this: `MyAdapterForList extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapterForList.MyViewHolder>`, [here](http://pastebin.com/RS7bWmDV) you have a sample adapter

Comment: Ok i study for it  , thanks @pskink

Answer (score 1):

Implement `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener` in your Activity class. Then you can do something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
    //gets the filtered list based on user entered text in search box
    final List<String> filteredList = filter(mList, query);
    //set the filtered list to adapter and do notifydataSetchanged in adapter class
    mAdapter.setFilteredList(filteredList );
  //  mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0); not required 
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}

// filters the existing list that's provided to the List Adapter
private List<String> filter(List<DriverInfo> mList, String query) {
    query = query.toLowerCase();

    final List<String> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String item : mList){
    if (item.toLowerCase().contains(query)) {
        filteredList.add(item);
        }
    }

    return filteredList;
}
```

In your adapter class create a method

```
public void (List<String> filteredList){
this.mList = filteredList;
notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks for your help ,do i need to use ActivityListItem in your case ? i don't get it.

Comment: When you'll initially set adapter to your listview then obviously there would be an list of data that you'll pass to adapter class either in constructor or some other method. using which adapter will inflate it into your listview. The same list should be used when you have to filter the results.

Comment: after try to work for it , i can understand what you say now. thanks @Mr. Bista

Comment: @徐博俊I answered the question. Mr.Bista just changed formatting of lines. Anyways good to hear you got your solution

Comment: i code all day , the mind was dizzy , sorry man ha , thanks to you @Mayank Bhatnagar

Answer (score 0):

On your `MyAdapterForList` add this method:

```
public void setMDatas( List<ActivityListItem> mDatas){
     this.mDatas = mDatas;
}
```

and on your fragment on `onQueryTextChange`:

filter the `List<ActivityListItem>` based on `newText`, smth like:

```
ArrayList<ActivityListItem> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
for(ActivityListItem item : yourActivityItemList){
 if(newText.equals(item.getYourField())){
   filteredList.add(item); 
 }
}
```

and refresh your `recyclerview` adapter with filteredList:

```
adapter.setMDatas(filteredList);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: i try your way , when i click the search icon and input something , my recyclerView will disappear . i don't get it..

Comment: Check if `filteredList` is not `empty` after you filter?

Comment: do you mean item have any value ?

Comment: no, is your `filteredList` being filled with any data?

Comment: well...the code cause the problem myAdapterForList.setMDatas(filteredList);
and my filteredList from item , and item from my arrayList
and my arrayList has a lots of String variable , is the problem ?
Sorry i just can't sure about it

Comment: Pobably your recyclerview is not dissapearing, but because the `filterdList` is empty and you set an empty list to `adapter.setMDatas(filteredList);` there is no item so it can be binded to the adapter

Comment: strange , my arrayList is not empty , otherwise i can't show my recyclerView at first.

Comment: i found another solution , if i add the data in filteredList  just the same time with my original arrayList , it will work.  thanks for your hekp @hrskrs

Answer (score 0):

add this function in you adapter class ,where data,and filterDAta is your array list .. You will use data everywhere in your holder class..

```
public void  filter(String charText) {

    charText = charText.toLowerCase();
    data.clear();

    if (charText.length() == 0) {

        data.addAll(filteredData);

    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0 ; i< filteredData.size() ; i++)
        {    System.out.println("its here5");

            if (filteredData.get(i).getVEHICLE_NO().toLowerCase().contains(charText))
            {
                System.out.println("its here");
                data.add(filteredData.get(i));


            }
        }
    }
     notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

and this is your searchView QueryListener

```
 searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()   {
           @Override
           public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
               return false;
           }

           @Override
           public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {


               mAdapter.filter(newText);

               return true;
           }
       });
```

and from activity Listview click listener will be like this ..

```
 mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            Arraylist_Type model = (Arraylist_Type) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);

     and use model after that ..
    like model.name();etc..

   }
    });
```

Comment: thanks for your help , but what's getVEHICLE_NO() , i chabge to toString is ok?  When i change like this , i click the search icon and the recyclerView data is disappeared , just like the other solution , i don't get it

Answer (score -1):

1st. Clone the original data list. This will make your search progress doesn't affect original data.

```
List<ActivityListItem> cloneMDatas = new ArrayList<>();
cloneMDatas.addAll(originalMDatas);
```

2nd. `//I just know i have set the filter right here`

```
for(int i = 0; i < cloneMDatas.size(); i++){
   if (!cloneMDatas.get(i).getName().contains(newText)){
      cloneMDatas.remove(i);
      adapter.notifyItemRemoved(i);
      i--;
   }
}
```

**NOTE:** Everytime you search, clone the original data to find.

That's my idea.

Comment: Sorry i don't get it , how do i clone the original data ?

Comment: i see it , is it all under on onQueryTextChange ? i test is has some effect when i input some words , but the search effect is not so smart.

Comment: Check if is correct first. After that, we can improve it @徐博俊

Comment: yap  i though it correct because it change , just the search result is strange.

Comment: i mean the search result is not correct data , i'm sure i get the correct data (from your getName)

Comment: I apologized i was using wrong algorithm. I have to add `i--` line to make it find `i` position again cos `i+1` position becomes `i` position.
Check it back. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133425/discussion-between-truonghieu-and-).

Comment: i still study for it , as far as possible i try more and more solution . thanks man